# html2canvas rendering bootstrap button with low opacity

Tags: html2canvas

Library [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) can take picture of your html content. But sometimes colors are not accurate.

Chrome is ok, Firefox has this problem. Does not occured while devtools are opened.

[image: Example of wrong colors rendering.]

```html
<div class="col-auto btn-group btn-group-toggle mb-2" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-xs border-0 active">
         <input type="radio" name="x" value="1" data-html2canvas-ignore="" checked="">Vývoj
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-xs border-0">
        <input type="radio" name="x" value="2" data-html2canvas-ignore="">Vybrané obodbí
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is becaouse buttons has transition to animate change of state.

```css
/* bootstrap button */
.btn {
    ...
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Html2canvas take a copy of your dom elements and render them to canvas.
To disable transition add style tag and remove it after render.

```js
// Create styleelement to disable transitions globally
$("head").append('<style id="html2canvas_no_transitions" type="text/css">* {transition: none !important;}</style>');

// Render
html2canvas(element, options)
    // Process canvas
    .then(canvas => whateveryouneedwith(canvas))
    // Remove style element 
    .finally(() => $('#html2canvas_no_transitions').remove());
```